# Do XYZ and MEAT Partners have any legal standing to stop their names from being used?

Tags: copyright, trademark, fair-use

Below is similar language to a note my team is preparing to send out to clients, announcing a recent transaction. Everything is factual. While XYZ and/or MEAT have asked us not to use their logo (and we will NOT use the logo)...is there anything contained in the promotional note to clients that would give XYZ or MEAT a legal-standing to order a cease and desist or stop us from stating their name in mentioning a deal we worked on?

*New Jersey (12/12/2019) – ABC ADVISORS, a leading business sales and valuation firm to the industry, announced today the successful completion of its most recent transaction. ABC ADVISORS provided guidance and buy-side services to XYZ Group, a Bozeman, MT mechanical provider since 1974, in the acquisition of  Quality MeatPacking Partners (“QMP”) by  XYZ Group subsidiary Meat Meat Meat, Inc. (“MEAT”).
ABC ADVISORS played a key role in facilitating the acquisition from its earliest stages. In particular, managing partner Wilson, Duke of Lizards at ABC ADVISORS, was responsible for bringing the parties together and helping negotiate a mutually beneficial transaction. Terms of the transaction were not disclosed
“Whenever you have a chance to work with a market leader like XYZ Group it is very exciting. Not only do we get to help  XYZ Group achieve their goal of expanding their first-class meatpacking footprint but we get a front-row seat to learn from them too, and they are one of the best in the business.”*

Additionally could the names/words "XYZ acquired MEAT" be displayed in simple text (no logos) on our website? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The logo is a work of art and thus is copyright protected.  The name of the company the logo represents is not copyrighted in and of itself and may be refereed to by a legal name in documentations so long as you do not use the logo image as requested.

Comment: Ok. Maybe I was not clear...We will NOT be using the logo, just the words I have provided

Comment: @Sizzle This is the correct legal answer ... but do you really want the management of XYZ and MEAT going around telling all their friends in various boardrooms "Never trust those bastards at ABC to keep a confidence; we *told* them we didn't want a press release but they went ahead and published anyway."

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica That is a fair point...and I'd be honored if they even mentioned our name in boardrooms (they won't) but we do not advertise and our team gains new business , clients and buzz by trumpeting our successes to potential clients and prospects. From our point of view..."hey XYZ, we brought you a deal you wouldn't have found without us, you paid us for it...and now you're saying 'don't tell anybody about the good work you do?' How about you suck lemons?" Seriously though...why would we not want to or be able to tell our clients about the work we are doing?

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica Additionally, this is not "publishing" a press release...it is sending a promotional announcement

Comment: @Sizzle I quite understand why you want to tell your clients about the work you are doing - but pissing off previous clients (when you trade on reputation) seems like a high risk strategy - but hey, your call.

Comment: One thing to watch out for is an NDA in the contract, I have seen contracts that stipulate that one or both sides won't disclose their relationship for the purpose of advertising.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian Thanks for the comment. XYZ actually signed my NDA...and I signed nothing of theirs so that isn't something to worry about here.